# Can't show the ads through TBannerAd

Tags: android, delphi, admob, firemonkey

I have Created a multi-platform app.
Putted a `TBannerAd`.
Checked the `Admob` Service.

This is on `FormShow` Event Code:

```
BannerAd1.AdUnitID:='ca-app-pub-xxx/xxx';
BannerAd1.LoadAd;
```

and then it gives error of `can't load ad Error Code: 1`
it is being said that the Error:1 is about wrong AdUnitID but it is not !
even if i am trying with test AdUnitID from Google which is

`ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111`

but it is giving the same error.
what to do to make it work ?

Comment: Check this (https://delphitipsandtrick.blogspot.it/2017/09/delphi-monetize-androidios-applications.html) article it may be useful!

Comment: Did the same at that time and was getting error. but now everything is solved. Thank you for giving time @AlbertoMiola.